# BigQuery - custom quota for query bytes scanned?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting this error any time i try do anything in BQ - cant seem to figure out exactly what quota i've run into or how to try request an increase that will resolve it - any ideas?

Custom quota exceeded: Your project exceeded the custom quota for query bytes scanned, which is set by your administrator. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/cost-controls

Comment: Can you please provide job id? It is a new feature we released this week

Comment: sure its bquijob_1d9916fb_15578695897 - getting it for every job i run. I did recreate a load of historic tables yesterday so have a feeling they might have caused it.

Comment: here is a jobid that is closer to when this was triggered. bqjob_r72fcbff6b44f9eec_0000015577ba8ed5_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, it looks like there is custom query cost controls enabled on the project. Here is information about cost controls and how to modify an existing quota.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/cost-controls

Comment: Ok cool - can you pm me what the current quota is by any chance - have forgotten what i requested the last time and cant seem to find it anywhere in the cloud console UI?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to pm a user in SO. Let me know if you would like me to provide the value of quota here (without any project details).

Comment: Hey, yeah that would be fine, I think it's 100tb

Comment: Accepted ad answer, I just needed to do a request to increase the limit and is fine now.